# how to input on visual studio code python

Tags: python, input, visual-studio-code

i have recently installed visual studio code, and i added python extension, and i have added the python path to **tasks.json** and **settings.json** and **launch.json** i can debug but i can't input data while the code is running, i have tried **Integrated Terminal/Console** but it's not working, this is the output :

```
C:\Users\Mugiwara303\Documents\VSCpython>cd null && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && C:\Users\Mugiwara303\AppData\Local\
Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:\Users\Mugiwara303\.vscode\extensions\donjayamanne.python-0.5.5\pythonFiles\PythonTool
s\visualstudio_py_launcher.py null 57138 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 WaitOnAbnormalExit,WaitOnNormalExit c:\Users\Mugi
wara303\Documents\VSCpython\.vscode\main.py "
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i have fix it! **"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",**  instead of  **"cwd": "null",**

```
{
    "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Mugiwara303\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python.exe",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit"
    ]
},
```